# PS - How can I remove a file name entry from a text file

Tags: powershell

I get a list of extracted files without their full path. They come in a txt file on seperate lines. These files can be found in different folders or subfolders. I'd like to delete the files from the list and remove the file name from the list only if they're older than 30 minutes.

list.txt example:

```
file1.doc
file2.doc
file3.doc
```

Let's say file3.doc is less than 30 minutes old. With my current code I can get as far as deleting file1.doc and file2.doc and not touch file3.doc no problem. I would like my code to remove file1.doc and file2.doc from list.txt as it deletes the files.

```
$Now = Get-Date
$Minutes = "30"
$TargetFolder = "C:\Test"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddMinutes(-$Minutes)

$Files = Get-Content C:\list.txt |% {get-childitem $TargetFolder -include $_ -recurse} | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}

foreach ($File in $Files)
    {
    if ($File -ne $NULL)
        {
        Remove-Item $File.FullName -WhatIf | out-null
        }
    }
```

I am a total beginner How would I go about removing the file name from the original list C:\list.txt?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here's a guide on [ask]. Generally questions should include code on what you've tried and where you have gotten stuck. If you are looking to use PowerShell, the `Get-ChildItem`, `Get-Content`,  `Remove-Item`, `Get-Date` Cmdlets would be what you would use. You can get details on how to use these with the `Get-Help xxx -Examples` where `xxx` is the command you want help on.

Comment: Also `Get-Content` as well ;)

Comment: Can't quite understand the problem statement. Could you give an example input, intended output and what you managed to get so far?

Answer (score 0):

I got it using Set-Content in the following manner. Feel free to comment if you think i'm doing something wrong, but this works me very well as it is.

```
$Now = Get-Date
$Minutes = "30"
$TargetFolder = $args[0]
$LastWrite = $Now.AddMinutes(-$Minutes)
$List = "C:\list.txt"

$Files = Get-Content $List |% {get-childitem $TargetFolder -include $_ -recurse} | Where {$_.CreationTime -le "$LastWrite"}

foreach ($File in $Files)
    {
    if ($File -ne $NULL)
        {
        Add-Content -path C:\deleted.txt -value ((get-date).ToShortDateString() + ' - ' + (get-date).ToShortTimeString() + '  ' + $File.FullName)
        Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null
        Set-Content -Path $List -Value (get-content -Path $List | Select-String -Pattern $File.Name -NotMatch)
        }
    }
```